# <p:row id="some-id"> attribute not working

Tags: primefaces

I am using the following code to generate the data in prime faces 3

```
<p:panelGrid id="table1">
    <p:row id="row1">
        <p:column id="column1">Column 1</p:column>
        <p:column id="column2">Column 2</p:column>
    </p:row>
</p:panelGrid>
```

The resultant table that appears in FF is as follow (taken from view-source of browser)

```
<table role="grid" class="ui-panelgrid ui-widget" id="myform:table1">
<tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="ui-widget-content">
        <td role="gridcell">Column 1</td>
        <td role="gridcell">Column 2</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here attribute ID is only working with panel-grid, how can it work with row or column. The tag documentation also says that they support ID. Please guide me where I am making mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure , but...

I think that if you use

```
<f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText value="someText"/>
</f:facet>
```

inside your column , then the `id` will be applied to your generated `th`

A workaround might be setting a `styleclass` to your `p:column` , that way it should be applied to your generated `td`

The said above with jquery selectors should be enough to access to all td's in the table...

Again , I guess there might be a better solution...

Comment: I am not using header. styleClass can be a alternate but at the moment I am considering a better solution that possibly assigns the ID to row. Thanks